# PySpark: Is there any possibility of creating dynamic number of DataFrame based on the Non Null values

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame:

| name | age | username | password |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| joe | 34 | Null | Null |
| alice | 21 | Null | Null |
| Null | Null | user1 | pass1 |
| Null | Null | user2 | pass2 |

from the above DataFrame, I want to create 2 DataFrame like this by finding the Null value columns, somehow:

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| joe | 34 |
| alica | 21 |

| username | password |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | pass1 |
| user2 | pass2 |

Is there any way to achieve this?

Sample JSON files under "source" directory:

```json
{
 "name": "joe",
 "age": 31
}

{
 "name": "alica",
 "age": 21
}

{
 "username": "user1",
 "password": "pass1"
}

{
 "username": "user2",
 "password": "pass2
}
```

Code:

```
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Test")
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .config(conf=conf) \
        .getOrCreate()

json_data = spark.read.json("source")
```

Comment: The problem statement is, the single directory location has multiple JSON files with a schema that can't be predictable. So, wanted to find a way to create separate DataFrames so that it can be saved to its respective location.

Comment: Could you add a file example (JSON) example and your code you have so far? That might help to answer your question as with the information so far it is not clear to me on which columns Null combinations you want to separate the decision to create new dataframes.

Comment: @AlexOrtner, I have specified the JSONs and Code snippet(edited the post), I want to accomplish the use case specified above

Answer (score 0):

If you have always the same fixed amount of columns I would just cover all cases with

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df2=df.where(f.col("name").isNotNull() & f.col("age").isNotNull() & f.col("username").isNotNull() & f.col("password").isNull())

df3=df.where(f.col("name").isNotNull() & f.col("age").isNotNull() & f.col("username").isNull() & f.col("password").isNull())

df3=df.where(f.col("name").isNotNull() & f.col("age").isNull() & f.col("username").isNull() & f.col("password").isNull())

df4=df.where(f.col("name").isNull() & f.col("age").isNotNull() & f.col("username").isNotNull() & f.col("password").isNotNull())

df5=df.where(f.col("name").isNull() & f.col("age").isNull() & f.col("username").isNotNull() & f.col("password").isNotNull())

... and so on
```

Comment: Yes, this is working 
But what if the schema(columns) are unknown, is there any possibilities for creating such  DataFrames?

Comment: you can use inferschema=True. 
E.g for a csv file spark.read.format("csv").options(header="true", inferschema=True,sep=";").load("test.csv")
header=True: uses the column names or in case of JSON attributes
inferschema=True tells Spark to try to find the data types automatically. Not working if there are only Nulls

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `select` +  `dropna()` :

```
df1 = df.select("name", "age").dropna()

df1.show()
#+-----+---+
#| name|age|
#+-----+---+
#|  joe| 34|
#|alice| 21|
#+-----+---+

df2 = df.select("username", "password").dropna()

df2.show()
#+--------+--------+
#|username|password|
#+--------+--------+
#|   user1|   pass1|
#|   user2|   pass2|
#+--------+--------+
```